# Lua C - decent LuaJIT-compatible way of throwing an error into a resuming coroutine

Tags: lua, coroutine

In short, while the code seems to work fine, I'm curious of whether less hacky approaches (than the ones I came up so far) with exist.

Suppose you create a coroutine via [lua_newthread](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_newthread), and later suspend it from a [cclocure](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_pushcclosure) via [lua_yield](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_yield). Your program takes a lap around non-Lua code, and it is now time to resume the coroutine via [lua_resume](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_resume), but - suppose the arguments that Lua code provided are *extremely illegal*, and we should give it an error to indicate that.

As you might know, you can't call [lua_error](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_error) (or [luaL_error](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_error)) on a state unless it's currently running. So the state must resume but immediately get hit by an error.

In 5.3 you would use [lua_yieldk](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_yieldk), provide a continuation function, and call lua_error or luaL_error in there. Et voilà.

But, alas - LuaJIT does not implement lua_yieldk, so what options are we left to?

1. A single-use hook

   Suppose the error message is stored in a `char error_text[256]`. We could then bind a per-instruction hook immediately before resuming,

   ```cpp
   lua_sethook(L, throw_error, LUA_MASKCOUNT, 1);
   int result = lua_resume(L, NULL, ret_count);
   ```

   and then unbind the hook and throw an error in there

   ```cpp
   void throw_error(lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar) {
       lua_sethook(L, throw_error, 0, 0);
       if (error_text == nullptr) return; // trust no one, especially yourself
       luaL_error(L, "%s", error_text);
   }
   ```

   Should string cleanup be required, you would of course prefer to concatenate `error_text` to `luaL_where(L, 1)` yourself before calling `_error`, as both `lua_error` and `luaL_error` do a long jump and thus will be the last thing your function does.
2. A Lua-side wrapper

   Suppose you decide to pull a somewhat node.js-like on this and have your C code resume with an `error, result` pair so that you could have a wrapper function like so

   ```lua
   function some(arg)
       local e, r = some_native(arg)
       if (e) then
           error(e)
       else
           return r
       end
   end
   ```

   Or maybe refactor your API entirely so that errors are also handled using the same pattern, but that's a story for another day.

Option 1 seems less hacky of two.

Option 2 seems less likely to cause any trouble.

I can't help the feeling that there's a much better way of doing this that I'm overlooking (after all, `lua_yieldk` is a relatively recent addition).

Comment: How about the good old *return `nil` + error message* approach?

Comment: For clarity, would this be for a wrapper Lua function like with option 2? If for throwing an error this way, I wouldn't be able to do this on C side / prior to resuming as that's unprotected area and Lua would throw a "panic" instead of setting state into error mode.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I completely understand your situation; maybe you can post a simplified example of what you want your code to do?

Comment: I did explain in the opening paragraphs - Lua code calls a C closure, which suspends the Lua state, and later resumes it. The problem is throwing an error into the state when it resumes (see: rest of the question).